# Automatically add to address book

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

How can I automatically add the email address to the address book using link in the email footer from Marketing Cloud.
Is it possible to have one link across all email platforms?

Comment: I believe there is no such thing because the email clients tend to implement it differently. The only somehow valid option would be to attach a vcf card. But i am not sure if this attachment might come with other side effects to your delivery rate (some clients might block you when you have attachments).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, by having a link in the footer that points to the [vcf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) file with your information it it. This will cause most email clients to ask the recipient, whether he/she wants to add this record to the address book.

Comment: can you include link on how to do this in marketing cloud?

Comment: I don't think you can host vcf files on SFMC. So you would need to place it on another domain, and just use simple <a href=""> to link to it.